# The callout for marker is not centered in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I make a callout (tip) for the marker like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    
    private GoogleMap map;
    
    ...

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0.0, 30.0))
            .title("title")
            .snippet("snippet"));
    }
}
```

As a result, the callout is not exactly above the marker, but to the right, like:

[image]

This appears for Android 7 (API level 24) Samsung Galaxy tablet.
But the callout is properly centered on other devices:

[image]

**Question**: Why is the callout off-center? What could be the reason?

Thank you for any comment/answer!

Note: In build.gradle I used:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Generally, bugs and feature requests for Google Maps Platform products, including Maps SDK for Android, has to be reported in the Google Issue Tracker. Here's a [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188870) to the Maps SDK for Android component in the Issue tracker. In the meantime, I tried to replicate the issue you are reporting on a simulator that runs API level 24 but I can't replicate the issue. The info window is properly displaying at the top-center of the marker.

Comment: @annkylah Thanks for the link! Yes you are right, It looks like the reason is not in the api level. This problem occurs on Samsung Galaxy tablet.